# find function which is in o(log^k(n)) for fixed value of k and in ω(1)

Tags: asymptotics

I need to find a function $f$ which is in $o(\log^{k} n)$ for fixed value of $k$ with $f = \omega(1)$. I know that for little $o$ the function should be strictly less than $c\log^k n$ for all $c$ and large enough $n$; and for little $\omega$ it should be strictly greater than $c\cdot 1$ for all $c$ and large enough $n$, but I am stuck here. How does one usually solve such type of problems?

Comment: @PålGD: That doesn't go to infinity.  $\log^{k/2} n$ works.

Comment: @Louis sorry for deleting my comment, what I meant was $\log^k(n) / \log^{k-1}(n)$.

Comment: @Louis I am still not sure how can the value be log^(k/2)n be greater than c.1

Comment: @PålGD wouldnt that turn out to be log(n) ?

Comment: Your understanding of $o$ and $\omega$ is flawed; see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try $f(n) = \log\log n$.

Comment: well i dont think it will satisfy ω(1). the value will be less than 1. we wont it strictly greater than it.

Comment: @Rahul As it happens, this $f$ is a solution to your question. Go over the definitions again. The condition $f = \omega(1)$ is the same as $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) = \infty$, which is certainly satisfied by my $f$.